# Bypass RabbitMQ "OK" dialog on install

Tags: 10.04, apt, debconf

When I install rabbitmq-server package  on Lucid, I always get a warning about upgrading from a previous version (even though no previous version is installed), and then I have to hit enter to dismiss the dialog. Is there any way to disable this prompt so I can do the install unattended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding to your preseed config  (assuming you are preseeding, as "install unattended"):

`rabbitmq-server    rabbitmq-server/upgrade_previous    note`

If not doing unattended install, can pass these options to debconf-set-selections (as root):

```
echo "rabbitmq-server rabbitmq-server/upgrade_previous note" | debconf-set-selections
```